# Fix overfull hbox floatrow

Tags: subfloats, floatrow

When using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package to layout figures with the caption to the side, I get a overfull `\hbox` errors.

```
Overfull \hbox (3.33331pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 23--23
```

If I set `\FBwidth-1` on each `\ffigbox` the error goes away. Hackish?

I have many figures that will be done this way, what is the proper way to do the `\subfloatrow` so this doesn't happen?

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \thisfloatsetup{valign=t,heightadjust=all}
  \fcapside[0.7\textwidth]{\fboxsep-1pt%
    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[]{}\label{fig:test15a}}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{sample1}}%
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[]{}\label{fig:test15b}}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{sample2}}%
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[]{}\label{fig:test15b}}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{sample3}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}
  }{
    \caption{Horizontal sub-figures, top aligned}%
    \label{fig:test15}%
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed one `%`

```
   \begin{subfloatrow}[3]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: I thought that spurious spaces were not taken into account in such situations. Why does it happen here?

Comment: @cjorssen `3.33331pt too wide` is just TeX way of saying `missing % at end of line` So I could have answered without looking at the code:-). TeX is designed to typeset text and space between words is significant. There isn't really (despite for example latex3 conventions) a separate programming layer in TeX, It's always trying to typeset something and spaces are significant unless the macros arrange to ignore them.

Comment: Good to know. I'm going to inspect every occurrences of `\begin{subfloatrow}` in files. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: @cjorssen might be simpler to suggest to the package maintainer he adds `\ignorespaces`